# where to place POST method on my webserver?

Tags: php, forms, post, joomla, plesk

I am hosting my first webserver ever. I got myself a ubuntu based vserver and installes plesk and joomla.

Stupid question, but I wanted to create a form and and handle the input with a post.php file with a POST-method. But I have no clue where to place it on my server. Right now it is just in `/var/www/vhosts/[MY WEBSITE.DE]/httpdocs/post.php`, but this might be wrong.

Is there a specific file that I have to change or do I have to place my php-files in a specific directory? This question might be so stupid, I couldn't even find an answer on Google :D

Comment: Can you reach your actual website with a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can place your own code anywhere in the directory that plesk is using for your website. In your case : `/var/www/vhosts/[MY WEBSITE.DE]/httpdocs/`.

It is then your job to use that in your code where needed (I assume you have a form of some sort and that's why you are talking about a "post method", you just need to point that form to your *whatever.php* page you uploaded).

Please use FTP/your website username to upload your code into your website directory and not the root user or you'll end up with permission issues and nothing will correctly work.

A good start would be [Getting Started with Managing Websites in Plesk](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/quick-start-guide/read-me-first.74371/) and [Option A. Upload Content](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/quick-start-guide/plesk-tutorial/step-6-change-your-password-and-log-out.74376/#option-a-upload-content)